# docker container exited with "Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?" message

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to setup docker containers for fullstack app: express, react. But something goes wrong and api container doesn't work. Can you help me please
https://github.com/flyoozes/react-full-stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you specify `volumes` in docker-compose.yml file it mounts folder when running container. And in your case docker overrides `/srv/app/api` folder and as result `node_modules` missing. You can comment out `volumes` for api services and the container will work.

However is better to add `/srv/app/api/node_modules` as 2nd volume to `api` service. This will mount the `node_modules` directory to the host machine using the buildtime directory.

Comment: Also check that the node_modules is in the path `ENV PATH /node/node_modules/.bin:$PATH`